# How to implement background messaging in Sinch library

Tags: android, sinch

I am using Sinch API and library for implementing messaging feature. I able to store the message on the phone and everything is working fine.

The problem is I cannot able to think of a way to transfer messages when the app is inactive.When the app is inactive,not even the service gets the message. I attached a notification with the Sinch service but I got no success. How should I progress ?

Comment: Have you checked out The gcm push?

Comment: I think that's the only way now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution of storing data in internal database mysql worked for me. :)